Docker build for Windows containers: "COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore"
I want to create a Windows Docker container.
So, I created a local directory, added all the necessary context files in there and added a Dockerfile to it.
The Dockerfile (in its current state) just defines some variables and a COPY instruction:
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2
ARG VSPath
ENV VSPath=${VSPath:-"C:\VsBuildInstall\"}
COPY [ "\LocalLayout\", $VSPath ]
...

When I try to build an image from this Dockerfile, I get the following error message:
docker build --rm -t test:latest '.'

Step 1/12 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2
 ---> d7c03b5bcc73
...
Step 9/12 : COPY [ "\LocalLayout\", $VSPath ]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat LocalLayout\,: file does not exist

According to the documentation, everything in my Dockerfile seems fine.
What am I doing wrong here?
Just for the sake of completeness and because I have no clue where to look for issues in my setup, I'll add a VS Code screenshot here:


Just for sake of ensuring the path is being passed on correctly, can you use WORKDIR instead of ENV?
You could use something like:
WORKDIR /VsBuildInstall
COPY . .

Also, you might want to remove the "". In fact, you might have an issue here with back and forward slashes. On Windows, A path is passed as something like: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app', but in the dockerfile, you can use /folder to indicate a local folder.
You might also use something like:
COPY default.aspx C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app

In the meantime, after checking the Docker source code, I realized that the Docker documentation is wrong to this regard. So, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/docker/docs/issues/19922
